# Time to fire for beforeunload vs. pagehide on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, events, safari, onbeforeunload

I'm using the `beforeunload` event to as a means to proxy into metrics about clicks on my site. For example, if `beforeunload` fires within ~50ms of a `click` event, I can determine when a user has selected a link.

This gets complicated with iOS, as it doesn't support `beforeunload`. As per Apple docs, I've substituted `pagehide` for `beforeunload`, but this doesn't have the same functionality. It looks as if `pagehide` replaces `unload` - NOT `beforeunload`. In my tests their time to fire differs by ~1500ms on average (`pagehide` triggers much later than `beforeunload`). This makes attributing `pagehide` events to clicks very difficult.

Is there any event supported by safari on iOS that can get close to the trigger time of `beforeunload`?

NOTE: I know this isn't ideal, and there are other, better approaches which I will likely end up pursuing, but I was still curious about this.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically `pagehide` is replacement for `beforeunload` in safari but practically its not. As correctly observed time to trigger `pagehide` event can vary because safari fetches the new page in the background and when page is available it fires `pagehide`.

There is no event if you are looking for one but there is this hack which you can try, as soon as **click happens safari stop running `requestAnimationFrame`**. So you can try something like this, as click happens record `clickTs` and start recording timestamp inside `requestAnimationFrame` function, now when `pageHide` fires you just check the time difference between `clickTs`and `eventlastReqAnimTime`, it should be roughly between 500 ms. This way you can attribute `click` to `pageHide`

```
var w = window,
reqAnim = null,
clickTs = 'record this when click happens',
eventlastReqAnimTime = +new Date,
logReqAnim = function() {
    eventlastReqAnimTime = +new Date;
    reqAnim = w.requestAnimationFrame(logReqAnim)
};
reqAnim = w.requestAnimationFrame(logReqAnim);
setTimeout(function () {
    w.cancelAnimationFrame(reqAnim);
}, 1500)
w.addEventListener('pagehide', function(){
    if(Math.abs(clickTs - eventlastReqAnimTime) < 500 ){
        console.log('your link was chosen')
    }
})
```

NOTE: above code is just pseudo, test before running.